# Restore database with different filename

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, restore

I have to restore a new back up file daily (as an agent job, after first deleting the existing db) but the file name will vary as it will include the timestamp as well.

How can I achieve this so that the restore operation will identify the new file? The name of the file will be something like this and always in the same directory: `AnyLetterGoesHere_TimeStamp.bak`

Thanks all

Comment: Are you restoring onto the same server (or a server with access to the original server)?

Comment: Exactly..No server change. The agent job will delete the existing db for the first step and will restore the bak file next. Only problem, the bak file name will change every day. (Some portion of it will always stay the same) Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to say: _The agent job will **backup** the existing database and then delete it and restore the .bak file to replace it"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a table variable(or temp table) and insert all the `.bak` file metadata in that table and then fetch the row with max value of modified time.

```
DECLARE @FileMeta table (columns nvarchar(200));

INSERT INTO @FileMeta 
EXEC sys.xp_cmdshell 'dir D:\FolderName\*.bak';

SELECT * FROM @FileMeta 
WHERE columns not like '%volume%' 
AND columns is not null and columns not like '%bytes%';
```

Now you can get the [creation date of the file as shown in this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/52c36c41-bf6e-49e6-aa90-4f3a85f20aaf/how-to-get-metadata-for-each-files-in-a-folder-using-tsql?forum=transactsql), and Now from this table `@FileMeta` You can get the row for Max of creation date that will give you the most recent file.

Comment: Hi mate..Thanks ..Looks like working now just trying out. Just a note; it worked after removing the GO statement as the table variable will be out of scope if left in place. Thanks.

Comment: Just a security question please: I need to enable xp_cmdshell in order to run this. Is it a good practice to set up the job so that it enables it before the execution and disables once complete?

Comment: Removed GO Statement in my answer, Thanks for correction.

Comment: @Stackoverflowuser, Check if this works. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2014/replace-xpcmdshell-command-line-use-with-sql-server-agent/